# JSX array.map only maps first item

Tags: arrays, reactjs, database, web, jsx

Nothing is displayed on the initial render, but the console logs show me 3 things:

1. The runs array contains 3 objects (How it should be)
2. Both times I use runs.map, it runs through only the first element in runs.
3. The component's render method runs twice before stopping.

If, after the first render, I make a change to my script and save it, the code executes as it should and everything appears on-screen.

This is how I'm creating my objects and populating the array.

```
    const [runs, setRuns] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        machineDocIDs.map(item => {
            fetchProductData(item)
        })
    },[machineDocIDs])

    function fetchProductData(id) {
        const productsCollectionRef = collection(db, "RunSheets", "All Runs", "Open", runID, "machines", id, "products")
        const q = query(productsCollectionRef)
        const productData = []
        const IDs = []
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                productData.push(doc.data())
                IDs.push(doc.id)
            })
            onCreateRunLocation(machines[machineDocIDs.indexOf(id)].machine_name, productData)
        })
        return () => unsubscribe()
    }

    function onCreateRunLocation(machine, productData) {
        let tempArray = runs
        let loc = {machine_id: machine, products: arrangeProducts(productData)}
        tempArray.push(loc)
        setRuns(tempArray)
    }

    function arrangeProducts(productData) {
        let temp = []
        productData.map((item) => (
            temp.push({name: item.flavors, quantity_ordered: item.quantity_ordered})
        ))
        return(temp)
    }
```

And this is all of my code involving the render

```
    function renderProduct(product) {
        return (
            <>
                <tr>
                    <th>{product.name}</th>
                    <th>{product.quantity_ordered}</th>
                </tr>
            </>
        )
    }

    function renderLocation(location) {
        console.log(location)
        console.log(runs)
        runs.map((item) => (
            console.log(item)
        ))
        return (
            <>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Title>{location.machine_id}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Table>
                            <tbody>
                                {location.products.map(item => (
                                    renderProduct(item)
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </>
        )
    }

    return ( /* main function return */
        <>
            <Container>
                {runs.map((item) => {
                    renderLocation(item)
                })}
            </Container>
        </>
    )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it:

```
 <Container>
     {runs.map((item) => {
          return renderLocation(item);
     })}       
 </Container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried it though and it didn't change anything